# Comparing pojos of different class with common properties

Tags: java, pojo

I have two sets of two different classes. Objects of these classes have few common properties. I want to merge the objects of these two sets together which have same values for common properties and create a third object.

For example:

```
class class1 {
   String A;
   String B;
   String C;
}


class class2 {
  String A;
  String B;
  String D;
}
```

I have two sets set1 with objects of class1 and set2 with objects of class2.

I want to create a set of class3 which is combination of class1 and class2 where A and B values of objects of class1 and class2 are equal.

```
class class3 {
   String A;
   String B;
   String C;
   String D;
}
```

Worst case I can iterate over two sets but I am trying to figure out if there is any efficient solution to achieve this.

Comment: You mentioned "same values" and "common properties" but in your example class3 contains the union of class1 and class2. Also, I don't think you can avoid iterating over the 2 sets. I would be more concerned about hardcoding the fields in my code.